# Raphael JS : width and height of the div and paper are different?

Tags: html, height, width, raphael

I'm using RaphaelJS to draw an SVG.
I have a div of the size 801 x 924.

I create a Raphael paper with the same sizes and assign it to that div:

```
var paper = Raphael('div', 801, 924);
```

I expect in the browser an SVG with the size of 801 x 924 pixels. 
But when I check the size of the svg in the browser (with inspect element), I see that the actual size is 514 x 606 pixels!
The svg-element has a width and height defined as 801 x 924, but it DISPLAYS as 514x606....

Why is that?  Is there some kind of DPI setting that I missed?  How do I create a Raphael of the exact same size as the div ?

Answer (score 0):

My mistake... I was copying paths of an existing SVG that had a VIEWBOX defined... so I thought my paths were absolute values, but in fact they were very different than what I saw in my svg-editor (Inkscape).  In Raphael you don't have to define a viewbox at all, so this is were it went wrong.